# Does cross-compilation affect application performance?

Tags: performance, arm, cross-compiling, cpu-architecture

Can it be said that the performance of a C application compiled for/running on an Intel architecture will be faster than the same application that is cross-compiled for an ARM architecture?

I'm essentially asking whether or not cross-compilation will have a negative affect on performance.

Thanks!

Comment: One should not expect different versions or in the case of gcc or llvm where there are compile time options for the compiler itself, the same version, built different times or places or that rely on different system libraries to necessarily give the same results for the same source code and the same target.  One simple test would be to be on an arm system and take the same gcc and binutils and create a native compiler and a cross compiler and see if you get the same results compiling the same test code.  Then repeat the cross compiler on a non-arm system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no, as a compiler should output the same machine code for a given architecture regardless of what architecture the compiler itself is running on.

Comment: Are the optimizations, O1, O2, and O3, the same across compilers on different architectures?

Comment: It depends, the optimizations that are done target independent sure, but if any are applied to the backend or are target specific then of course those will vary from one target to another.  As far as cross compiler vs native for the same target, one would expect them to produce the same results.

Comment: And all software should not have portability bugs.